# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon on Windows 7

Tags: windows, docker, boot2docker

I see a couple of entires for this error but not on Windows 7. I have installed Client version 1.5.0 (Client API 1.17) in to my Windows 7 SP1 machine. I followed the Windows Install instructions with no problem. I run Boot2Docker Start and it is started successfully. However, when I run the docker version command I am informed on version details with a FATA error message below stating:

FATA[0000] Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?

When I run docker -d I am told there is a permission error:

INFO[0000] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
FATA[0000] open /var/run/docker.pid: permission denied

I have tried a chmod on the pid file and have checked I am running with Administrator privilege on the Windows machine. I am not sure whether the permission denied is a red herring.

As it appears Windows 7.1 is supported and the install appeared to run smoothly without errors, I am wondering if anyone has come across this problem or has any ideas as to what try next?

Many thanks, rvon

Comment: have you checked whether virtualization is enabled in the bios?

Comment: Hi Jimmy, yes I have enabled virtualisation through the BIOS VT-x setting.

Comment: I should clarify: virtualisation was enabled before Docker install and I still am encountering this problem. I have tried a few recommendations (e.g different VirtualBox install) with no success.

Comment: there's a whole load of boot2docker commands e.g. boot2docker init - have you experimented with those? I think "boot2docker download" gets the latest iso. Also, can you ping the docker iso vm from windows?

Comment: Yes, I now am well versed in the boot2docker commands. A delete and re-init and new download all work fine. I still get the same error. It does appear maybe the permission line is relevant but I am running as admin and have tried chmod/chown changes. I am going to try a Vagrant install as it will also meet my needs. Thanks for your suggestions.